# Can Git push / pull over the internet to distributed repos?

Tags: git

I understand that Git can be used without a central repository. However, I am starting a project with several other people, and we are geographically distributed. I.e. We will never be on the same LAN to synch repos.

So my question: Is it possible to push / pull changes from each others repos over the internet? If so, how do I go about it? Easiest non-fuss way.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: if you can access the machine on the other end via ssh you can push/pull with git

Comment: Thanx for the great responses. Was thinking to go with github, but was just wondering if that was the preferred / easiest way, or whether the purely distributed route was the way to go.
I'll probably stick with github then.

Comment: GitHub is the least hassle solution by far

Comment: GitHub is great, but costs money for private repositories, and is sometimes slow to respond (far slower than a direct SSH to another developer machine), or down for maintenance -- I use it, but don't absolutely rely on it. Even with a centralised repository set up it's good to explore the various ways you can synchronise in a decentralised way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have SSH access to each others' machines (which may be a little easier to set up on some networks than git:// protocol access) then it's as easy as:

```
git pull ssh://username@host:/path/to/repository/.git
```

If direct access by any protocol isn't possible (e.g. if you're behind a router with NAT) then you can always send each other patches.

But Git has another way of doing this, `git-bundle`, which lets you send a file (via email, or however else you send files) to your collaborators which can be pushed and pulled to and from  like a repository. The author of *Pro Git* has a [blog post tutorial on this](http://git-scm.com/2010/03/10/bundles.html).

Answer (score 5):

If you can ssh to each others' computers, you can do git push/pulls to each other's computers. However, it's not really recommended to have a completely peer-to-peer repository. One of you should maintain a "bare" repository that everyone synchronizes with, otherwise [you will run into strange and annoying situations when you push to a repository that someone else is working on.](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_won.27t_I_see_changes_in_the_remote_repo_after_.22git_push.22.3F)

It's really probably best to use github, unless you are working on something closed-source and can't afford the fees for private repositories.

Answer (score 3):

You need some kind of "direct" not-nat-ed connection (meaning if you are behind a router it is a problem). If I were you I'd go for [github](http://github.com/)

The help section explains everything nicely.

Comment: you can be behind a router as long as your in in a dmz zone of the router.

Comment: I don't use it myself, but it's clear from many other questions that users have successfully used git via ssh on windows boxes; the port forwarding is just a quick router setting. Do note that for closed-source projects another option is to pay for private git hosting.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop: Please, please don't open *all* ports to your own computer just to get the single one for SSH opened.

Comment: @Jefromi Yes, SSH works great with Git, even with Windows boxen.  Just install Cygwin there...

Comment: I can't explain it well, therefor I suggest REALLY using a well supported community site. I mean, there is no pain in that little indirection and get very nice functions for free. There is nothing better. Personally I use it even without collaboration.

Comment: who said I opened all ports to just get ssh? DMZ doesn't mean all ports are open it means you aren't behind the NAT of the router. You can still close whatever ports you want on the DMZ machine.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop: On a home router, if you tell it to make a DMZ out of a given computer, it will open all ports to it. Apologies if you were talking about a more robust DMZ with subnet and dual firewall and everything, but it's a bad idea to just suggest to a home user "make a DMZ".

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a central repository location that you can all push and pull from via ssh. This will prevent the issue mentioned above that are caused by pushing to a repo someone is working in.

See this link for good setup info:

http://toolmantim.com/thoughts/setting_up_a_new_remote_git_repository